# How to set record per page limit in report viewer?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I want to set Records per page limit (i.e. 25) in Report Viewer.

so how can i set ? I am new in ReportViewer.

Comment: i think there is no such option to set records per page limit in Crystal reports.. it is purely your design of report and dynamic data content which set the records..

Comment: I am not talking about crystal report . i am talking about reporting tool report viewer.

Comment: u tagged the question in crystal-report that's why i commented on it. by the way it is not possible to set number of records. in any viewer, report viewer are page wise, depending on the size you define...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a custom expression.  See this page for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328(v=sql.90).aspx

See the section under the heading "Page Breaks".

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("RowsPerPage", "50", false));
rptReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList);
```